# Where can I find a conceptual UML model of airline crewing activities?

Tags: software

I would like to know if anyone has created a UML model of the various elements of a typical crewing system. I have found online UML models for ticketing and reservation systems. However I would rather be interested in the crewing aspects. Here are the things I would like to model:

- Flight Logs
- Crew Activities
- Pairings, legs
- Etc...

Comment: I imagine airlines would keep that information proprietary, especially if it includes algorithms showing how they choose flight legs and balance resources like aircraft and crews since those directly effect profit.

Comment: Actually the crewing problem is well documented since it is a typical mathematical optimization problem.